# Unrecognized VM option 'UseBiasedLocking' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java, scala, gatling

I was previously using Java 17 for creating and running tests in Gatling.

I wanted to run an old test suite written in Scala so I installed Scala using the Homebrew command:

`brew install coursier/formulas/coursier && cs setup`

Now when I attempt to run my Java suite it is giving these errors:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseBiasedLocking
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.854 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-11T12:54:17+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:4.1.5:test (default-cli) on project performance-test-assignment-api: Gatling failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

**"Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)"**

Not sure why it is not compiling now since the current Java version is still 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanted to run an old test suite written in Scala so I installed Scala using the Homebrew command:

Why would you do that? You don't need to "install Scala", scala is just library that maven will pull.

> brew install coursier/formulas/coursier && cs setup

This is installing coursier, unrelated.

> io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:4.1.5

Your issue is here: you're using old `gatling-maven-plugin` `4.1.5`. Upgrade to latest version (`4.2.7` atm).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar case.
Usually, it happens with "old" apps which were written under Java7 or Java8
and a user tries to run them in Java 11+ environment.
There are a lot of JVM options that have been decommissioned.
`UseBiasedLocking` was decommissioned in Java 15.

It can be fixed in several ways:

1. Search for the command line which starts your app and adds additional parameters to JVM and remove this flag (if you are really sure that it can be removed).
2. You can add to this command line a flag `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions`. In this case, JVM will ignore all unrecognized flags.