# Karate Performance testing : Getting build failure with error "Unrecognized VM option 'UseBiasedLocking'

Tags: karate

I am trying to reuse Karate tests for performance testing with Gatling and Scala.
I have configured everything as described in documentation. But then when I run the mvn command I am getting error "Unrecognized VM option 'UseBiasedLocking' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine."
mvn command used to run tests: mvn test-compile gatling:test

Tried with looking at Env path variables and running the mvn command with different options. But still getting same error

Failed to execute goal io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:4.1.5:test (default-cli) on project PerformanceTesting: Gatling failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

Below is the POM file
[image: POM File]

Scala File
[image: scala file]

Comment: this has never been reported - sorry I'm pretty sure no one can help - so you have to troubleshoot this on your own. my best guess is the JDK is not set up correctly, this tends to happen on windows: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/404

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved after upgrading the gatling.plugin.version to 4.2.7 as my Java version 19 is not supporting old gatling plugin.

Below article helped to resolve

[Unrecognized VM option 'UseBiasedLocking' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027869/unrecognized-vm-option-usebiasedlocking-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtu)

Comment: glad you got it working and thanks for contributing this knowledge back to the community !